# Font looks different in different browsers

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have used "Raleway" font in my webpage. But looks different in different browsers. Is there any way to fix the problem?

Here is the link that I have used.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" />
```

Below is the image in crome and firefox view:

[image: Click here to check Crome & firefox view image]

In firefox fonts look little bit bold and shadowed.

Comment: My View: the various types of browers to rendering the output sometimes differently. May be try this it will help to you http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/  and   http://blog.typekit.com/2011/07/26/new-from-typekit-improved-font-rendering-on-windows/

Comment: I've tried this but it won't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use This.

```
body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -o-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-smoothing: antialiased
}
```

If not working

```
body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased!important;
    -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased!important;
    -o-font-smoothing: antialiased!important;
    font-smoothing: antialiased!important;
}
```

Comment: Got smoothening after using this, but the bold and shadow effect in firefox is still there.

Comment: `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` `-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;` use this

Comment: Also tried -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; but it does not support in my firefox version. I have gone through the below link, it states that it is not appropriate to use this solution, because it will not work for every user.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth

Comment: Try `text-shadow: none;` or `font-weight:` **you want** or please use other font like **lato**, **open sans** etc

Comment: if you use old version browser then please update and try ... **THANKS**

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, there is some issue with the font-weight.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```